# Change quote background color, to make code in a quote stand out

Tags: feature-request, css

The

> quote background `(this is inline code)` color

```
is the same as code background color.
```

Please change it because code sometimes appears in quotes.

(I realize meta has a different theme but the problem's the same on Super User)

---

## Use case:

#### Before:

> [image]

#### After:

> [image]

Comment: They're actually slightly different. Code is #EEE and quote is #F0F0F0. But my eyes don't notice the difference.

Comment: No, on SU they are both #EEE

Comment: Can you provide an example of 'code in a quote' on SU?

Comment: Note that the "Before" did not actually use a quote.

Answer (score 4):

Here's current use examples so it's easier for everyone to understand what's going on.

I've actually noticed this before and been bothered by it, so I think it would be a good idea to fix this in some fashion.

**Code:**

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit`

**Code block:**

```
Nulla et nibh sed quam sodales porttitor.
Curabitur sed nisi et dolor bibendum dignissim.
Vivamus viverra tincidunt ante non ornare.
```

**Quote**:

> Curabitur vestibulum tellus non ligula pharetra tempor

**Code inside a quote**:

> Vestibulum `lacinia volutpat leo ac ultricies`. Duis tristique ante ac

**Code block inside a quote:**

> Proin varius nibh non est ultrices tincidunt.
>
> ```
> Curabitur vestibulum tellus non ligula pharetra tempor.
> Sed imperdiet luctus dui, eu aliquet dolor malesuada id.
> ```
>
> Vestibulum faucibus laoreet tristique. Etiam vel nisi lectus.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest doing like on Meta Stack Overflow, where code formatting inside a quote is made darker to make it more visible. This is how it looks there:

[image]

Alternatively, only Meta Super User could do like Meta Stack Overflow, and Super User could have a yellow background for quotes like Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the much better "code in quote" in [an answer on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175800/what-causes-the-pop-up-to-view-this-web-content-you-need-to-install-the-java-r/229853#229853) and [the same content looking horrible Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1048562/which-application-is-triggering-a-to-use-the-java-command-line-tool-you-need/1048993#1048993):

[image: Code in quote on Ask Different] [image: Code in quote on Super User]

In general I'm still not happy about having a separate Apple community, but their CSS is much better in my opinion...